# On which position do I have to parse? (Java, RegEx)

Tags: java, regex, string, parsing

I'm having a problem using RegEx in JAVA.

I've got this String:

```
String str = FOOD(ID:8,FRUIT[(NAME:v,CAL:2),(NAME:b,CAL:5)])
```

And I have written this RegEx to check if the String ist matching it. (regexr.com says it's okay):

```
FOOD\(ID:\d,FRUIT\[\(NAME:[a-zA-Z],CAL:\d\)(,\(NAME:[a-zA-Z],CAL:\d\))*\]\)
```

But it doesn't work when I do the following:

```
String patternTo = "FOOD\(ID:\d,FRUIT\[\(NAME:[a-zA-Z],CAL:\d\)(,\(NAME:[a-zA-Z],CAL:\d\))*\]\)"; //Error at this point
Pattern lP = Pattern.compile(patternTo);
return (lP.matcher(str).matches());
```

I know that I have to parse it with \ . But I don't know on which position.
I will be really grateful when someone gives me a hint to solve this problem.

Comment: you have to escape the backslashes with backslashes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each backslash character needs to be escaped with another backslash:

```
String patternTo = "FOOD\\(ID:\\d,FRUIT\\[\\(NAME:[a-zA-Z],CAL:\\d\\)(,\\(NAME:[a-zA-Z],CAL:\\d\\))*\\]\\)";
```